# Swapon failed trying to enable zram

Tags: android

I'm trying to enable zram with these commands

```
echo 77512704 > /sys/block/zram0/disksize
mkswap /dev/block/zram0
swapon /dev/block/zram0
```

When I press enter to the last command I get this error: swapon failed for /dev/block/zram0. Why? How can I solve?

Also when I press enter to mkswap I received this: swap file needs to be at least 40 kb. I solve it inserting 80000000.. Thanks in advance for any help.

P.S. To disable ZRAM I use

```
swapoff /dev/block/zram0
```

and works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable zram.

for android:

## root user

```
su
```

## disabled

```
swapoff /dev/block/zram0
```

## reset

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/zram0/reset
```

## set size

```
echo 128M > /sys/block/zram0/disksize
```

or

```
echo $((128*1024*1024)) > /sys/block/zram0/disksize
```

## enabled

```
mkswap /dev/block/zram0
swapon /dev/block/zram0
```

Answer (score 0):

If `mkswap` fails then `swapon` will fail too...

You might try the following command to initialise 80MiB zram disk:

```
echo $((80*1024*1024)) > /sys/block/zram0/disksize
```

This method of setting size is better.